# Await not returning since Chromium update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, async-await, chromium

Has anyone had that problem with the most recent versions of Chromium-based browsers?

My app worked in previous versions, and it works on firefox. But now there's a failure due to one await call never giving hand back.

Logs show that the resolve function of the awaited Promise should be called.

I'll admit that my code is a bit special but I checked everything and see no reason why it should fail. It uses a web worker quite intensively for a couple of seconds.

Sometimes the whole thing works even on Chrome, so it could be a time-sensitive bug. Maybe caused by the garbage collect?

The Promise that is awaited looks like this

```
if (this._closestFreePointResolve)
    throw new Error('busy')
console.log('created')
new Promise(resolve => {
    this._closestFreePointResolve = resolve
})
```

And it's resolved like this in another method

```
if (!this._closestFreePointResolve)
    throw new Error('expected resolver')
const resolve = this._closestFreePointResolve
delete this._closestFreePointResolve
console.log('resolving')
resolve(val)
```

The console output looks like this:

created
resolved
created
resolved
... (the pattern repeats itself and always ends with resolved)

Await code:

```
let a
try {
    a = await b(c)
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
}
```

No error appears in the console

Comment: What does your `await` code actually look like?

Comment: This code looks strange/bad practice, please post more of it

Comment: @Dominic What happens between these two blocks of code is basically a postMessage to a web worker, which then posts a message back. That's why the resolve function is kept as an instance variable. I'm not so sure there is a good way to do it :) p.s. I added an answer to my own question.

Comment: @JoshLee it was missing a try/catch clause (but no errors are caught when I reproduce the bug with try/catch)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that adding `this._promise = promise` to ensure the promise is kept in memory fixes the bug.
And `delete this._promise` before resolving it.

Based on this fact I guess that a chrome update introduced a more aggressive garbage collection for that specific case.

It's weird that calling `resolve` does not throw any error, and that the Promise is apparently garbage collected when there's an `await` in progress AND a solid reference to `resolve`.